# Default font size for ListTile's title property in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

What is the default font size for ListTile's title property in Flutter? Also, is there a quick and easy way to know font styles / sizes / color of different UI elements at run time?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly all the default values of `ThemeData`, but `ListTile`'s title property always sets its texts to the following `TextStyle`: `Theme.of(context).textTheme.title`. You can define your own `ThemeData` and set its `textTheme`'s `title` property to change `ListTile`'s titles. This also applies to colors. Similarly, `ListTile`'s subtile property always sets its texts to `Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle`

Check out the [documentation on Theme Data](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html) for more info on its properties.

Comment: FYI, now the style used for ListTile title is called titleMedium